# Strange error: Can't render polygon

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I use a `MKMapView` to display about 700 annotations in total. My issue is that sometimes I get a huge log like this:

```
2013-06-05 17:32:12.395 tiet[1493:1c52b] Can't render polygon (can't reserve indicies: 324): featureID: 1547811419 key: 73.35.7 (512)
2013-06-05 17:32:12.396 tiet[1493:1c52b] Can't render polygon (can't reserve indicies: 480): featureID: 1547811419 key: 73.35.7 (512)
2013-06-05 17:32:12.396 tiet[1493:1c52b] Can't render polygon (can't reserve indicies: 30): featureID: 1547811419 key: 73.35.7 (512)
2013-06-05 17:32:12.396 tiet[1493:1c52b] Can't render polygon (can't reserve indicies: 18): featureID: 1547811419 key: 73.35.7 (512)
2013-06-05 17:32:12.396 tiet[1493:1c52b] Can't render polygon (can't reserve indicies: 18): featureID: 1547811419 key: 73.35.7 (512)
2013-06-05 17:32:12.397 tiet[1493:1c52b] Can't render polygon (can't reserve indicies: 1818): featureID: 1547811419 key: 73.35.7 (512)
2013-06-05 17:32:12.397 tiet[1493:1c52b] Can't render polygon (can't reserve indicies: 18): featureID: 1547811419 key: 73.35.7 (512)
2013-06-05 17:32:12.397 tiet[1493:1c52b] Can't render polygon (can't reserve indicies: 18): featureID: 1547811419 key: 73.35.7 (512)
2013-06-05 17:32:12.397 tiet[1493:1c52b] Can't render polygon (can't reserve indicies: 18): featureID: 1547811419 key: 73.35.7 (512)
2013-06-05 17:32:12.397 tiet[1493:1c52b] Can't render polygon (can't reserve indicies: 234): featureID: 1547811419 key: 73.35.7 (512)
2013-06-05 17:32:12.397 tiet[1493:1c52b] Can't render polygon (can't reserve indicies: 90): featureID: 1547811419 key: 73.35.7 (512)
2013-06-05 17:32:12.398 tiet[1493:1c52b] Can't render polygon (can't reserve indicies: 174): featureID: 1547811419 key: 73.35.7 (512)
2013-06-05 17:32:12.398 tiet[1493:1c52b] Can't render polygon (can't reserve indicies: 18): featureID: 1547811419 key: 73.35.7 (512)
2013-06-05 17:32:12.398 tiet[1493:1c52b] Can't render polygon (can't reserve indicies: 162): featureID: 1547811419 key: 73.35.7 (512)
2013-06-05 17:32:12.398 tiet[1493:1c52b] Can't render polygon (can't reserve indicies: 186): featureID: 1547811419 key: 73.35.7 (512)
2013-06-05 17:32:12.398 tiet[1493:1c52b] Can't render polygon (can't reserve indicies: 114): featureID: 1547811419 key: 73.35.7 (512)
2013-06-05 17:32:12.398 tiet[1493:1c52b] Can't render polygon (can't reserve indicies: 18): featureID: 1547811419 key: 73.35.7 (512)
2013-06-05 17:32:12.398 tiet[1493:1c52b] Can't render polygon (can't reserve indicies: 120): featureID: 1547811419 key: 73.35.7 (512)
2013-06-05 17:32:12.399 tiet[1493:1c52b] Can't render polygon (can't reserve indicies: 78): featureID: 1547811419 key: 73.35.7 (512)
2013-06-05 17:32:12.399 tiet[1493:1c52b] Can't render polygon (can't reserve indicies: 126): featureID: 1547811419 key: 73.35.7 (512)
2013-06-05 17:32:12.399 tiet[1493:1c52b] Can't render polygon (can't reserve indicies: 192): featureID: 1547811419 key: 73.35.7 (512)
2013-06-05 17:32:12.399 tiet[1493:1c52b] Can't render polygon (can't reserve indicies: 18): featureID: 1547811419 key: 73.35.7 (512)
2013-06-05 17:32:12.399 tiet[1493:1c52b] Can't render polygon (can't reserve indicies: 30): featureID: 1547811419 key: 73.35.7 (512)
2013-06-05 17:32:12.400 tiet[1493:1c52b] Can't render polygon (can't reserve indicies: 156): featureID: 1547811419 key: 73.35.7 (512)
2013-06-05 17:32:12.400 tiet[1493:1c52b] Can't render polygon (can't reserve indicies: 18): featureID: 1547811419 key: 73.35.7 (512)
2013-06-05 17:32:12.400 tiet[1493:1c52b] Can't render polygon (can't reserve indicies: 18): featureID: 1547811419 key: 73.35.7 (512)
2013-06-05 17:32:12.400 tiet[1493:1c52b] Can't render polygon (can't reserve indicies: 84): featureID: 1547811419 key: 73.35.7 (512)
2013-06-05 17:32:12.400 tiet[1493:1c52b] Can't render polygon (can't reserve indicies: 30): featureID: 1547811419 key: 73.35.7 (512)
```

I've been unable to find anything regarding the error, and am completely baffled. There are no real visual discrepancies that i can see, and there are no other errors. Anyone got any idea what this is all about?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for that? I'm having the same issue right now

Comment: @gasparuff The project this was regarding to has been completed months ago, but as far as I can remember I eventually just accepted the errors as a slipup by Apples errorchecking system. IIRC Occasionally error messages that are only supposed to occur on their own debug logs end up in distribution builds. I couldn't find any cause for this error and ended up hoping that whatever was going on was being fixed by the system at the same time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't render polygon (can't reserve indicies: XX): featureID: X key: XXXX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23966911/cant-render-polygon-cant-reserve-indicies-xx-featureid-x-key-xxxx)

Comment: @simpleBob, please read that question again, that user also referring to this question.

Comment: Possible answer is here, http://stackoverflow.com/a/23969763/1603234

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
I also had the same problem once in iOS6.1.
I was zooming out the map based on a coordinate which was (0.00000,0.00000).
In my code:-
CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate ;
    theCoordinate.latitude = [[self.dicOfMAP objectForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue];
    theCoordinate.longitude = [[self.dicOfMAP objectForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue];

    self.pointAnnotation.coordinate = theCoordinate;

the value of theCoordinate was(0.0,0.0).
So check the value of coordinate.
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have no time to test this solution, but suspect this to be the cause, as was originally answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23969763/1603234)