# Can't render polygon (can't reserve indicies: XX): featureID: X key: XXXX

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mkmapview

I have use **Mac OS X 10.9.3** and **Xcode 5.1.1**

In my app I have to use `MKMapView`, It's all are working fine but in iOS 6.1, I have stranger error display in console, such like,

```
Can't render polygon (can't reserve indicies: 1482): featureID: 0 key: 0.0.1 (512)
Can't render polygon (can't reserve indicies: 570): featureID: 0 key: 0.0.1 (512)
Can't render polygon (can't reserve indicies: 30): featureID: 0 key: 0.0.1 (512)
Can't render polygon (can't reserve indicies: 390): featureID: 0 key: 0.0.1 (512)
Can't render polygon (can't reserve indicies: 330): featureID: 0 key: 0.0.1 (512)
Can't render polygon (can't reserve indicies: 18): featureID: 0 key: 0.0.1 (512)
Can't render polygon (can't reserve indicies: 30): featureID: 0 key: 0.0.1 (512)
Can't render polygon (can't reserve indicies: 18): featureID: 0 key: 0.0.1 (512)
```

Like as a [This question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943146/strange-error-cant-render-polygon)

**I want to know about this error and why this is displaying in iOS 6.1 and how can I solve it?**

My code is:

```
self.mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] init];
self.mapView.frame = CGRectMake(30, 30, 140, 105);
[self.mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
[self.mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
[self.mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];
[self.mapView setDelegate:self];
self.mapView.layer.borderWidth = 1;
self.mapView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
[self.scrollView addSubview:self.mapView];
self.pointAnnotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
[self setMAPAnnotationAndCallout]; /// custom method for set annotation pin and callout

-(void)setMAPAnnotationAndCallout
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate ;
    theCoordinate.latitude = [[self.dicOfMAP objectForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue];
    theCoordinate.longitude = [[self.dicOfMAP objectForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue];

    self.pointAnnotation.coordinate = theCoordinate;
    self.pointAnnotation.title = @"Title";
    self.pointAnnotation.subtitle = @"SubTitle";
    int region = 8000;
    MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [self.mapView regionThatFits:MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(theCoordinate, region, region)];
    [self.mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - MKMapView Delegate Methods

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
{
    MKAnnotationView *aV;
    for (aV in views)
    {
        CGRect endFrame = aV.frame;
        aV.frame = CGRectMake(aV.frame.origin.x, aV.frame.origin.y - 230.0, aV.frame.size.width, aV.frame.size.height);
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.70];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
        [aV setFrame:endFrame];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)sender viewForAnnotation:(id < MKAnnotation >)annotation
{
    static NSString *reuseId = @"StandardPin";
    MKPinAnnotationView *aView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[sender dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:reuseId];
    if (aView == nil)
    {
        aView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseId];
        aView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        aView.canShowCallout = YES;
    }
    aView.annotation = annotation;

    return aView;
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
    [mapView deselectAnnotation:view.annotation animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also had the same output in my console on iOS 6.1.

In my case the problem was that I tried to zoom out the map based on a coordinate which was (0.00000,0.00000), and it created strange rendering problems **only in the first time that I opened the map.** after I re-opened the map it worked correctly.
But when the coordinate wasn't (0.00000,0.00000), it always worked.

Maybe you should check that the value of `theCoordinate` is what you want it to be.